# Why is space inserted at beginning of table or figure caption when using macros to define caption label?

Tags: macros, floats, captions

Here is my MWE. As you can see, the problem only happens when we use the macro \suppOrApp.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\title{A caption test}
\author{Some one}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\suppOrApp}{
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{thesisStyle}}
    {Appendix}
    {Supplementary}
}
\newboolean{thesisStyle}
\setboolean{thesisStyle}{false} % Might want to reconsider this here.


% This has additional space:
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf{\suppOrApp Table}}
% But this would work fine.
%\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf{Supporting Table}}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{mytable}
\end{table}

\blindtext

Please refer to Supporting Table~\ref{mytable}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing an end-of-line `%` here: `\newcommand{\suppOrApp}{%`

Comment: See (possible duplicate): [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)